# VIM Semantic JavaScript completion with YouCompleteMe?

Tags: javascript, vim, code-completion

is there any way to get **semantic** javascript code completion in VIM?

I've tried YouCompleteMe (YCM) and it gives me some code completion, however it is purely based upon my current buffer (or buffers?).

When I explicitly call `:YcmCompleter`, I get

`ValueError: No semantic completer exists for filetypes: ['javascript']`

I'm mostly working in node:sails.js and angularjs. I'd really appreciate a way of getting library methods suggested while typing  (e.g. for angular, protractor / mocha / jasmine).

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think YCM supports any kind of JavaScript semantic completion engine. [`Tern`](http://ternjs.net/) is a semantic engine for JavaScript, and there's a [Vim plugin](https://github.com/marijnh/tern_for_vim) for it, but I'm not sure how well it would work alongside YCM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These answers being very outdated, and since I've struggle a little bit with it, here is an update:

Javascript semantic support in Vim with YouCompleteMe is now supported via [TSServer](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/tree/master/src/server) engine as explained in Ycm's [HUGE readme](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe#javascript-and-typescript-semantic-completion)

I've got the information thanks to : https://medium.com/parallel-thinking/actually-great-vim-javascript-completion-eaefa1cb443d

Answer (score 4):

From [YCm's huge README](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe#semantic-completion-for-other-languages):

> YCM will use your omnifunc (see :h omnifunc in Vim) as a source for semantic completions if it does not have a native semantic completion engine for your file's filetype. Vim comes with okayish omnifuncs for various languages like Ruby, PHP etc. It depends on the language.

[Tern for Vim](https://github.com/marijnh/tern_for_vim) provides the kind of completion you are looking for via Vim's native omni-completion (`<C-x><C-o>`). With that plugin installed, YCM should be able to use it transparently for JavaScript completion.

Comment: you're right, it should. Apparently there's work being done in that direction [link](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/pull/724)

Comment: AFAIK there's nothing to do. Omni-completion fallback was added shortly after I submitted [this issue (#3)](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/3) so YCM *should* use whatever function is registered for JavaScript completion via the `omnifunc` option. That said, I removed YCM for good even before the author replied to my issue so I suggest you turn to YCM's issue tracker for any further request.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment there is no semantic completer for javascript available in YouCompleteMe. However, people are working on that. Here is the [pending pull request](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/pull/724) for integrating JS Tern.

Without semantic completer available you are indeed limited to language agnostic completers, such as the identifier completer, filepath completer and snippet completer.

UPDATE: [Tern has been integrated into YCM](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe/pull/1849)

Comment: But issuing `ctrl + Space` does show a list of semantic completions. Isn't there anyway to root this semantic autocompleter YCM suggestions list?

Comment: No, it's the way YCM is designed. By default only the identifier completer is active. The semantic completer is triggered when you type a period `.` (because that's the attribute operator in javascript. For toplevel semantic completions you have to press ctrl-space to ask for them explicitly.